# jQuery UI Sliders - Select overlapping sliders based on dragging direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have this simple jQuery UI Slider setup with a range and a two default values that overlap. The entire thing (with a few bells and whistles) can be found in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/XeyGS/

```
$('#slider').slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 11,
    range: true,
    values: [4, 4]
});
```

The problem with this is that when you attempt the drag the single visible handle to the right, it fails, because jQuery UI always places the minimum handle on top. This is obviously bad, for a number of reasons.

Is there a way to allow jQuery UI to choose which handle to drag depending on which direction the user starts dragging?

Comment: I have just updated my answer please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091747/ui-slider-overlapping-slider-impossible-to-drag/38743988#38743988)

Answer (score 6):

Ah, I like it to eat through 11k libs, don't you too? :)

**Note:** The following is for jQuery UI 1.8.5

Anyways, here's a pretty clean solution:

```
// add some stuff to the slider instance
this._handleIndex = null;
this._handleStartValue = -1; 

// remember the starting values in _mouseCapture
this._handleStartValue = this.values( this._handleIndex ); 
this._mouseDownOffset = this._normValueFromMouse( { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY } );


// modify _mouseDrag
oldValue = this.values( this._handleIndex ),
curValue;

curValue = this.values(this._handleIndex);
if ( curValue === oldValue && this._handleStartValue !== -1 ) {
    if ( normValue - this._mouseDownOffset > 0
         && ( curValue === this.values( ( this._handleIndex + 1 ) % 2 ) )
         && oldValue === this._handleStartValue) {

        this._handleIndex = (this._handleIndex + 1) % 2;
    }

} else {
    this._handleStartValue = - 1
}

// reset everything in _mouseStop
this._handleIndex = null;
this._handleStartValue = -1;
```

And that's all there is to it, oh how it works, of course:

1. Save the starting mouse offset as well as the value of the initially select handle
2. When dragging compare the old value to the current value of the active handle and also check whether the start position is valid
3. In case there's no difference we check whether there would be a difference if the active handle could be dragged further
4. If that's the case we check whether both handles have the same value, that means they're on top of each other
5. Now we check if the the currently selected handle hasn't been dragged yet
6. And finally if all that is true, we switch the handles
7. In case the user now changes the value we invalidate our start position so that there's no more switching between the handles

And for your pleasure here's a `diff`:

```
9960c9960,9962
< 
---
>       
>       this._handleIndex = null;
>       this._handleStartValue = -1; 
10215a10218,10219
>         this._handleStartValue = this.values( this._handleIndex ); 
>       this._mouseDownOffset = this._normValueFromMouse( { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY } );
10243c10247,10249
<           normValue = this._normValueFromMouse( position );
---
>           normValue = this._normValueFromMouse( position ),
>           oldValue = this.values( this._handleIndex ),
>           curValue;
10246c10252,10263
< 
---
>       curValue = this.values(this._handleIndex);
>       if ( curValue === oldValue && this._handleStartValue !== -1 ) {
>           if ( normValue - this._mouseDownOffset > 0
>                && ( curValue === this.values( ( this._handleIndex + 1 ) % 2 ) )
>                && oldValue === this._handleStartValue) {
>             
>               this._handleIndex = (this._handleIndex + 1) % 2;
>           }
>         
>       } else {
>           this._handleStartValue = - 1
>       }
10257a10275,10276
>       this._handleStartValue = -1; 
>       this._handleIndex = null;
```

Save it to `ui.diff` then do `patch -i ui.diff jquery-ui.js`.

Answer (score 4):

With apologies to Ivo there, whose [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239458/jquery-ui-sliders-select-overlapping-sliders-based-on-dragging-direction/4249476#4249476) there I'm sure took a lot of effort to create. The problem is that I couldn't apply that solution, because I'm already on 1.8.6, I can't find the 1.8.5 sources anywhere to apply it to, and somehow I just couldn't get the patch to work for 1.8.6, even when I tried adding in the lines manually.

The following is my solution to the problem. It is simpler than Ivo's, but that might be because of differences between the two point releases. The solution is as follows:

1. Splice in an additional variable to keep track of the original values
2. When the conditions are met, (two handles, same value, new value larger than current), to flip an internal variable (`_handleIndex`) around, causing the maximum handle to be used for reference for the internal `_slide` function instead of the first.

The `diff` is as follows:

```
46a47,48
>       
>       this._originalVal;
310a313,314
>       
>       this._originalVal = this.values();
323a328,331
>       
>       if(this._originalVal[0] === this._originalVal[1] && normValue > this._originalVal[0]){
>           this._handleIndex = 1;
>       }
```

The first part should be inserted into the initialising area, where the variables are declared, the second into the `_mouseCapture` function right before the call to `_slide`, and the last part into the `_mouseDrag` function, also right before the call to `_slide`.

**Here's a working example with the patch: http://www.jsfiddle.net/HcGXZ/**

A copy of the patched jQuery UI 1.8.6 Slider file can be found here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/jQuery%20UI%20Slider%20Patch/jquery.ui.slider.patched.js

As always, this patch has not been extensively tested and is not guaranteed to work for all scenarios.

Comment: Awesome, just utilised this, with the addition of Dr. Gibbs answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5901216/892397) in the latest jQuery UI (1.8.18). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is a bug, doubly so because there's already logic preventing a ‘deadlock’ from happening when both slider handles are at the minimum / far left position:

```
// workaround for bug #3736 (if both handles of a range are at 0,
// the first is always used as the one with least distance,
// and moving it is obviously prevented by preventing negative ranges)
if( o.range === true && this.values(1) === o.min ) {
  index += 1;
  closestHandle = $( this.handles[index] );
}
```

It looks like [ticket #3736](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3736) is still open, with mentioning of the specific problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

I tried [Yi Jiang's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239458/jquery-ui-sliders-select-overlapping-sliders-based-on-dragging-direction/4254932#4254932) with 1.8.12 and it broke on a slider with a single handle, but worked perfectly after I changed

```
this._originalVal = this.values();
```

to

```
this._originalVal = this.options.values === null ? this.value() : this.values();
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this into the initialising area, where the variables are declared:

```
this._originalVal;
```

Put this into the `_mouseCapture` function right before the call to `_slide`:

```
this._originalVal = this.values();
```

And this into the `_mouseDrag` function, also right before the call to `_slide`

```
if (this._originalVal[0] === this._originalVal[1]
      && normValue > this._originalVal[0]) {
    this._handleIndex = 1;
} else if (this._originalVal[0] === this._originalVal[1]
             && normValue < this._originalVal[0]) {
    this._handleIndex = 0;
}
```

I just added an `else if` to the above code; it's working fine in jQuery 1.8.14 for 
both left and right button handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:
Test for both values and if they are the same, return to the last step.

```
 $("#slider").slider({ 
            range:true, 
            min:0, 
            max:250,
            step: 25,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                if (ui.values[0] == ui.values[1]){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    $( "#amount" ).html( "&euro;" + ui.values[0] + " - &euro;" + ui.values[1] );
                }
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a new version for jQuery UI 1.10.2

Patch file: http://pastebin.com/Dsxw8NYR

Complete file: http://pastebin.com/ibSpAAX1