# UI Slider Handle Overlap UX-Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, user-interface, user-experience

The jquery-ui slider widget has a small but significant flaw.
When both slider handles overlap each other and one wants to select a handle it will always select the first handle no matter what. In my case I have moved the handles apart from each other(even though they overlap) so that one can actually select both handles but even if you click on the right handle the active handle will always be the left-hand one.

I've had a quick look at the ui-slider source and will try to prototype the plugin. For the life of me I couldn't find the method that assigns the 'active" class to a handle so that I can change its' behaviour...

Here's the link to the example on jqueryui.com:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Comment: I've found the answer somewhere else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239458/jquery-ui-sliders-select-overlapping-sliders-based-on-dragging-direction